# Perl - DateTime module - trouble assigning DateTime object value to variable

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a hash that looks like:

```
%info = { 
          'EVENT_START' => '27 Jul 2018 17:02:00.000',
          'EVENT_END'   => '27 Jul 2018 17:05:30.220',
          'EVENT'       => { 
                             'ACCELERATION_SEC' => '30.7',
                             'STILL_SEC' => '30.8195',
                             'STILL_END' => '27 Jul 2018 17:35:13.083'
                           }           
        };
```

I tried to convert these hash entries into DateTime objects and then perform calculations with them:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Duration;

my $parse_time = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%N');

my $event_start = $parse_time->parse_datetime($info{"EVENT_START"});
my $event_end   = $parse_time->parse_datetime($info{"EVENT_END"});
my $still_end   = $parse_time->parse_datetime($info{"EVENT"}{"STILL_END"});

($sec, undef) = split /\./, $info{"EVENT"}{"ACCELERATION_SEC"};
$duration = DateTime::Duration->new( seconds => $sec );

print "1) event start $event_start\n";

$lower_bound = $event_start;
$lower_bound->add_duration($duration);

print "2) event start $event_start\n";
print "3) lower_bound $lower_bound\n";

($sec, undef) = split /\./, $info{"EVENT"}{"STILL_SEC"};
$duration = DateTime::Duration->new( seconds => $sec );

$upper_bound = $lower_bound;
$upper_bound->add_duration($duration);

print "4) lower_bound $lower_bound\n";
print "5) upper_bound $upper_bound\n";
```

The output of this is:

```
1) event start 2018-07-27T17:02:00
2) event start 2018-07-27T17:02:30
3) lower_bound 2018-07-27T17:02:30
4) lower_bound 2018-07-27T17:03:00
5) upper_bound 2018-07-27T17:03:00
```

This looks like the line `$lower_bound = $event_start` (and the other similar line) assigns a reference to `$event_start` rather than the value of `$event_start`, to `$lower_bound`. But I'm not sure how to pass the value of this DateTime object instead of a reference to it.

Comment: Tip: `$duration = DateTime::Duration->new( seconds => $sec ); $upper_bound->add_duration($duration);` can be written as `$upper_bound->add( seconds => $sec );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `clone` method for `DateTime` objects:

> $dt->clone()
>
> This object method returns a new object that is replica of the object upon which the method is called.

Which then yields:

```
main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> use DateTime

  DB<2> $start = DateTime->now();

  DB<3> print $start;
2018-08-09T19:05:03
  DB<4> $later = $start;

  DB<5> $later->add(years => 1000);

  DB<6> print $later;
3018-08-09T19:05:03
  DB<7> print $start;
3018-08-09T19:05:03
  DB<8> $start = DateTime->now();

  DB<9> $later = $start->clone();

  DB<10> $later->add(years => 1000);

  DB<11> print $later;
3018-08-09T19:05:39
  DB<12> print $start;
2018-08-09T19:05:39
```

As for reason, conceptually it helps if you remember that basically an object in Perl is a reference to an hash (and for the rare cases that it is not, it is still a reference to something, and the below applies in the same way), so when you do `$to = $from` it is like doing `$ref2_to_hash = $ref1_to_hash` and of course if you change anything into the `$ref1_to_hash` hash it will apply to the other variable since they are 2 distinct variables (2 separate names) but with a value being the same reference to a (single) hash.

Or clearer:

```
main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> $ref1 = { foo => 42 }

  DB<2> print $ref1
HASH(0x7fce9800af68)
  DB<3> $ref2 = $ref1

  DB<4> print $ref2
HASH(0x7fce9800af68)
  DB<5> $ref1->{foo} = 'bar';

  DB<6> print %$ref1;
foobar
  DB<7> print %$ref2;
foobar
```

Objects are blessed references on hash, typically, and if we add `bless` to the above the results are the same:

```
main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> $ref1 = { foo => 42 }

  DB<2> print $ref1;
HASH(0x7f939e80af68)
  DB<3> bless($ref1, 'whatever');

  DB<4> print $ref1;
whatever=HASH(0x7f939e80af68)
  DB<5> $ref2 = $ref1;

  DB<6> print $ref2;
whatever=HASH(0x7f939e80af68)
```

Note that the output change to show that the hash reference is blessed in some namespace, but it has no impact on the address (the underlying hash it points to).

(Of course, to be complete, but especially tricky, one could use `overload` to change the behavior during/after the `=` operation and then do like a clone automatically or other things. See "Copy Constructor" in `man overloading` and also the consequences of "fallback".)

Back to `DateTime`, while not related to your problem, the above also shows that you can use `add()` directly, it is a shortcut over `add_duration` with a `DateTime::Duration` object.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for!